# Combing multiple variables into a new variable in R

Tags: r, if-statement, cut

This is probably very simple for someone but I can't seem to make it work for the life of me.  I've tried using cut and ifelse but I get levels without the values I want.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.  Here's some fake data:

```
 o5<-c(1,0,2,0,0,NA)
 o6<-c(NA,0,NA,2,0,NA)
 o7<-c(0,0,NA,2,2,1)
 ID<-seq(1,6,1)
 d1<-cbind(ID,o5,o6,o7)

     ID o5 o6 o7
[1,]  1  1 NA  0
[2,]  2  0  0  0
[3,]  3  2 NA NA
[4,]  4  0  2  2
[5,]  5  0  0  2
[6,]  6 NA NA  1
```

I'm trying to combine o5,o6,o7 into an o_all variable that would look like this:

```
     ID o5 o6 o7 o_all
[1,]  1  1 NA  0  5
[2,]  2  0  0  0  0
[3,]  3  2 NA NA  5
[4,]  4  0  2  2  6
[5,]  5  0  0  2  7
[6,]  6 NA NA  1  7
```

each o variable indicates the grade level of student.  If they have a nonzero value for that grade, they should get the value of the grade level in o_all (this is grade that onset of a specific behavior was witnessed).  If they indicate in two or more grades, then I select the earliest value (ID #4 is an example of this). I have quite a bit of missing data that I need to accoutn for as well. Thanks!

Comment: These all worked for me with a little tweaking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1 <- cbind(d1, o_all = apply(d1[, -1], 1, function(x) {
  i <- which.max(!is.na(x) & x > 0) 
  if(x[i] == 0) 0 else i + 4
}))
#     ID o5 o6 o7 o_all
#[1,]  1  1 NA  0     5
#[2,]  2  0  0  0     0
#[3,]  3  2 NA NA     5
#[4,]  4  0  2  2     6
#[5,]  5  0  0  2     7
#[6,]  6 NA NA  1     7
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
res <- cbind(d1,o_all = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", colnames(d1[,-1]))[apply(d1[,-1], 1, function(x) which((x!=0))[1])]))
res
     ID o5 o6 o7 o_all
[1,]  1  1 NA  0     5
[2,]  2  0  0  0    NA
[3,]  3  2 NA NA     5
[4,]  4  0  2  2     6
[5,]  5  0  0  2     7
[6,]  6 NA NA  1     7
```

Then you can replace the `NA` by `0` e.g. through `res[is.na(res[, 5]),5] <- 0`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fully vectorized approach that potentially could be faster than the `apply` loops as the data set grows. The possible down back here is that I'm converting the zeros to `NA`s too as they both treated the same way

```
is.na(d1) <- d1 == 0L
indx <- (rowSums(is.na(d1)) == (ncol(d1) - 1L)) + 1L
max.col(!is.na(d1[, -1L]), ties.method = "first") + c(4L, -1L)[indx]
## [1] 5 0 5 6 7 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to iterate over each row, selecting the column with the maximum value:

```
result <- apply(d1,1,function(row){which.max(row[2:length(row)])})
```

Note that I use `row[2:length(row)]` to exclude the `ID` column.
This will give you a result like:

```
> result
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3
```

which you can use to assign to your `o_all` column:

```
o_all <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "",colnames(d1)[result+1]))
cbind(d1,o_all)
```

Comment: The second entry won't be correct with your methodology